# How to find the area of a rhombus with two given side lengths and given height?

Tags: polygons

Link to the Rhombus: [Rhombus with given side lengths of 11 and a height of 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXCaP.png)

Edit: I just realized that this rhombus is a parallelogram so because the 8 inches is the height and that the 11 inches is the base, I can simply times the 8 inches by the 11 inches to make 88 inches^2, so I think the answer is 88 inches^2.

Comment: Hi, please provide some context, such as what you have tried or any other relevant information in order to make this question suitable for our site.

Answer (score -1):

Notice that there is a square of 8 inch sides inside of the rhombus. Calculate the area of the square first and then the area of the two other triangles that make up the rhombus.

Comment: Thank you very much for that response, that is greatly appreciated and I hope you have a good day.

Comment: Please do not answer questions that do not meet our site's quality standards.

Comment: I mean he had a question so I awnsered there's nothing much to it

Comment: Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.